# Android Studio: install an update patch

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to update android studio from 1.2 to 2.0

I downloaded the required files (Windows: https://dl.google.com/dl/android/studio/ide-zips/2.0.0.1/android-studio-ide-143.2461418-windows.zip (320 MB)) from

http://tools.android.com/download/studio/canary/latest/

So, now how can apply these files on my android studio version to be updated to 2.0

Regards

Comment: Just unzip and go to /bin/ to find the studio.exe.You needn't update.You can just use it directly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Steps to install Android Studio from a .zip folder:**

If you have Windows:

- Open the .zip folder using Windows Explorer.
- Click on 'Extract all' option in the given in the ribbon.
- Enter the extract location. Extract them.
- Go to the extract location. Go to android-studio\bin and run
  studio.exe.
- Go through the installation wizard. You are done.

Hope it will help you.

Comment: you know what is a patch? and how to update it?

Comment: @GvSharma You have to first delete the current android studio folder in C -> Program Files -> Android in order to remove the old version. Then extract the zip file to this location before installing the application from the bin folder as above. Select I don't have a version of android studio on my P.C. and it will automatically detect the sdk that was installed with the previous version. Select it and everything else should work on default install settings.